# Is it possible to build a fully interactive web app on top of SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, business-intelligence, ssrs-2012

I'm new to MS BI tools and after reading a bit, I feel that SQL Server + SSIS + SSAS would fulfill my needs on the modelling and analysis side.

However, on top of it, I would like to build a web application that allows the user to select what to present on columns, rows, which filters to apply and which kind of chart to represent the data into. (drag and dropping or whatever, using HTML). Of course, after modelling the data on SSAS. So it should be somehow like exposing the report builder inside a web app.

I was wondering whether there's a possibility to do so consuming the Web Services that I've read SSRS exposes, because for sure building such a solution by hand-coding would be quite complex. Or are those WS, in contrast, just made for displaying reports already created using Visual Studio enablers? Also I've read of creating RDL reports and then rendering them, is this somehow possible and connected to what I'm looking for?

If it's not possible, what would be the alternative, if any?

Thanks

Comment: Like report builder? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220460.aspx You can probably do this in power pivot too (although it in excel). There are many BI tools besides the MS tools that can do this.

Comment: What I want is to be able to customize the solution and present it into a web application but at the same time, don't reinvent the wheel, since for sure there are tons of code behind this report builder, report designer, etc. Of course you can use a BI tool desktop application, but I want customization, since I want to present additional information, not only coming from the DWH and I suppose the code of this Report builder is not open, so I cannot extend its functionality, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the SSRS Web Service methods (find this here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155071.aspx) you will see that none of the methods allows for the functionality of creating a report from scratch.

Most if not all, of the methods are used to interact with existing reports. For example if you want to retrieve metadata of the report or of the report manager as a whole e.g retrieve a list of reports, retrieve a list of report paramaters.

You can also execute administrative tasks programatically using the web services, such as executing a schedule, moving reports from one location to another in report manager etc.

Putting a web interface on top of these functions seem suitable.

However to build an actual report from scratch through web services alone doesn't seem possible. The only way i can think of doing that would be to build up the XML structure of an RDL programmatically. To do that will be quite an undertaking and to be honest you are better off creating the reports manually.

As an alternative I'd consider moving to a self service BI tool such as Power BI/Excel (if you are stuck on the MS BI stack) or alternatives such as qlikview or tableau. In which case all you need to do as a developer is create the data model or dataset required for analysis and leave it up to the user to visualise a report.

Comment: Yes, that was my fear and the reason of my question. The problem is that neither qlikview/tableau nor power bi/excel will help, since I want to add some other data not coming from the DWH into another parts of the report (not relational data that doesn't fit into). I read about the RDL possibility, but as you said, the complexity of such a project would be quite huge and the result wouldn't perform as well as the report builder. However the alternative is not integrating both "worlds" and that's not nice. Would it be possible to somehow just startup the report builder from my web app?

Comment: Report Builder is accessible via a link so you can open up report builder directly from your web app using a simple link. Have a look here for more information https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337424.aspx

Comment: Great! I think we have a hit. And does it support user authentication administered by my application?

Comment: I'm not sure. However report builder is mostly just an extension of the report manager, so the security can be handled through the report manager most likely. But im not sure about that, its going to have to be something you look into.